# How to select max N consecutive rows that respect specific condition

Tags: python, if-statement

I want to choose rows that have 3 =< '1/1' and 3 =< '0/0' values in columns from P1-25 to P1-95 and my code does it.
Then I would like to allow for rows that do not respect either 3=<1/1 or 3=<0/0 if and only if they are max 2 consecutives and both conditions are respected before and after the rows in my question can be allowed multiple times (that situation is possible in many places on chromosome so I want to count it for finding as long sequences as possible) and can occur at the beginning or end of the dataframe.
However I don't know how to implementt this second condition.

Here is a part of my input (`drop_dots_str`):

```
   #CHROM       POS  ID REF ALT      QUAL  FILTER P1-25 P1-93 P1-88 P1-6 P1-89 P1-26 P1-12 P1-92 P1-22 P1-90 P1-28 P1-95
0    chr4  21414093 NaN   G   A   5860.45     NaN   1/1   0/0   0/0  NaN   1/1   NaN   1/1   0/0   1/1   1/1   1/1   1/1
1    chr4  21414456 NaN   G   T   6193.43     NaN   1/1   NaN   NaN  1/1   1/1   1/1   1/1   0/1   1/1   1/1   1/1   1/1
2    chr4  21414488 NaN   A   G   6060.10     NaN   1/1   NaN   NaN  1/1   1/1   1/1   1/1   1/1   1/1   1/1   1/1   1/1
3    chr4  21414503 NaN   A   T   5185.69     NaN   1/1   NaN   NaN  0/0   1/1   0/0   0/1   0/0   1/1   1/1   0/1   1/1
4    chr4  21414519 NaN   G   A   5284.15     NaN   1/1   NaN   NaN  0/0   1/1   0/0   0/1   0/0   1/1   1/1   0/1   1/1
5    chr4  21414661 NaN   C   T   2616.28     NaN   0/1   NaN   NaN  1/1   0/0   1/1   0/1   1/1   0/0   0/0   0/1   0/0
6    chr4  21414687 NaN   T   G   5543.03     NaN   0/1   NaN   NaN  0/0   1/1   0/0   0/1   0/0   1/1   1/1   0/1   1/1
7    chr4  21414699 NaN   C   T   3485.62     NaN   0/1   NaN   NaN  1/1   0/0   1/1   0/1   1/1   0/0   0/0   0/1   0/0
8    chr4  21414731 NaN   T   C   9951.07     NaN   1/1   NaN   NaN  1/1   1/1   1/1   1/1   1/1   1/1   1/1   1/1   1/1
9    chr4  21414765 NaN   G   A   2352.89     NaN   0/1   NaN   0/0  0/1   0/0   1/1   0/1   0/1   0/0   0/0   0/1   0/0
10   chr4  21414820 NaN   C   A   1962.20     NaN   0/1   NaN   NaN  0/1   0/0   0/1   0/1   0/1   0/0   0/0   0/1   0/0
11   chr4  21414829 NaN   T   A   3814.69     NaN   0/1   NaN   NaN  1/1   0/0   1/1   0/1   1/1   0/0   0/0   0/1   0/0
12   chr4  21414877 NaN   C   T   3708.44     NaN   0/1   NaN   NaN  1/1   0/0   1/1   0/1   1/1   0/0   0/0   0/1   0/0
13   chr4  21414892 NaN   C   T   2127.91     NaN   0/1   NaN   NaN  0/1   0/0   0/1   0/1   0/1   0/0   0/0   0/1   0/0
14   chr4  21414893 NaN   T   C   6534.38     NaN   0/1   NaN   NaN  0/0   1/1   0/0   0/1   0/0   1/1   1/1   0/1   1/1
15   chr4  21414901 NaN   G   A   2472.10     NaN   0/1   NaN   NaN  0/1   0/0   0/1   0/1   0/1   0/0   0/0   0/1   0/0
16   chr4  21414905 NaN   G   C   6554.19     NaN   0/1   NaN   NaN  0/0   1/1   0/0   0/1   0/0   1/1   1/1   0/1   1/1
17   chr4  21414915 NaN   T   G  14486.40     NaN   1/1   NaN   NaN  1/1   1/1   1/1   1/1   1/1   1/1   1/1   1/1   1/1
18   chr4  21414950 NaN   T   C   8061.63     NaN   0/1   NaN   NaN  1/1   0/0   1/1   0/1   1/1   0/0   0/0   0/1   0/0
```

and here is the code:

```
# checking if in row there are >= 3 1/1 AND >=3 0/0
lines = drop_dots_str.splitlines()
result = []
for line in lines:
    cols = line.split()
    samples = cols[8:]
    print(samples)
    homo_1 = 0
    homo_2 = 0
    for pos in samples:
        if pos in "1/1":
            homo_1 += 1
        elif pos in "0/0":
            homo_2 += 1
    if homo_1 >= 3 and homo_2 >= 3:
        result.append(line)
    print(homo_1, homo_2)
print(*result, sep="\n")
```

I'll be grateful for any suggestions. Thanks!

Comment: Is there a particular logic you have to follow when selecting max 2 rows that do not respect both criteria?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I suggest you to rewrite the first part

```
import pandas as pd
cond_11x3_true = (df.iloc[:,8:]=="1/1").sum(axis=1)>=3
cond_00x3_true = (df.iloc[:,8:]=="0/0").sum(axis=1)>=3
result = df[cond_11x3_true & cond_00x3_true] # pick
```

This will do the whole thing. The max 2 rows condition is based on the clarification in the comment below:

```
import pandas as pd
df=pd.read_clipboard()
maxrows=2
cond_11x3_true = (df.iloc[:,8:]=="1/1").sum(axis=1)>=3
cond_00x3_true = (df.iloc[:,8:]=="0/0").sum(axis=1)>=3
#both triplets
cond_both_true = (cond_11x3_true & cond_00x3_true) 
#identify consecutive false
cond_max_2_rows = (cond_11x3_true & cond_00x3_true).cumsum()
#identify where consecutive false is >maxrows
cond_max_2_rows = cond_max_2_rows.groupby(cond_max_2_rows).transform('size')<=maxrows+1 
#at least one triplet
cond_1_true_and_max_2_gaps = (cond_11x3_true & ~cond_00x3_true) | (~cond_11x3_true & cond_00x3_true) 
# pick only if consecutive false <=maxrows and at least one triplet
cond_1_true_and_max_2_gaps = (cond_1_true_and_max_2_gaps & cond_max_2_rows)
#filter out where neither condition is respected
result = df[cond_both_true|cond_1_true_and_max_2_gaps]
```

Comment: Thank you for the tips @CAPSLOCK. The logic of selecting max 2 rows that do not respect the criteria is connected with the data type I'm working on. The data represents genome sequencing results for 12 samples (P-25, P-93, and so on). I need to filter it to find regions on chromosomes (as long as possible) that have samples: 3 =< '1/1' and 3 =< '0/0' also, I want to allow for max two gaps because of the data type (sometimes in the genome the regions with 3 =< '1/1' and 3 =< '0/0' can be interrupted by gaps and I want to count it).

Comment: @emor I am not sure I fully got your logic. You want to include rows that do not respect either 3=<1/1 or 3=<0/0 if and only if they are max 2 consecutives and both conditions are respected before and after the rows in question? Should this be allowed only once or multiple times? What if the two rows are at the beginning or end of the dataframe?

Comment: Yes, @CAPSLOCK, you understand it correctly. Rows that do not respect either 3=<1/1 or 3=<0/0 if and only if they are max 2 consecutives and both conditions are respected before and after the rows in my question can be allowed multiple times (that situation is possible in many places on chromosome so I want to count it for finding as long sequences as possible) and can occur at the beginning or end of the dataframe.

Comment: @emor Updated the answer accordingly

Comment: Thank you, @CAPSLOCK! Please, clarify one thing: line described as #at least one triplet means that `cond_1_true_and_max_2_gaps` picks rows with  3=<1/1 OR 3=<0/0? If I want to pick only rows with  3=<1/1 AND 3=<0/0 and include max 2 consecutives then I should use `result = df[cond_both_true | cond_max_2_rows]`?

Comment: @emor that is correct.